# explorer.exe crashing with HEAP_CORRUPTION randomly when using WIN+TAB

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, crash, dump

When I open timeline (either via WIN+TAB or button) and use it to select another window, explorer crashes and reloads. Nature seems to be random, sometimes it doesn't crash for few days uptime and sometimes it crashes on first use.

Log:

```
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.18362.207, time stamp: 0xc5943461
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x00000000000f9269
Faulting process id: 0x1960
Faulting application start time: 0x01d54523eefff52c
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\Explorer.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: a8ea31ed-face-4a92-bb99-feea31579b6a
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I've managed to save a minidump, but got no luck understanding exact cause.

link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JNdQtsIlFyM91u-w5gA8AkTJUQpzMhtV

Comment: Might be caused by an Explorer extension. Check if it happens when booting in Safe mode.

Comment: I've recently disabled most extensions (except 7z context menu, which I've had for years), still happens. Not tested in Safe mode though, considering random crash nature.

Comment: Which exact version of Windows?

Comment: 1903 (18362.239)

Comment: Checks to do: (1) `chkdsk`, (2) [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html), (3) [dism](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html).

Comment: I have also looked at the minidump, and the crash happens within a memory management function. I suggest also running [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) and keep it running for as long as you can.

Comment: chkdsk - done, sfc - done, will run dism tomorrow. I've tested memory with windows test, will get memtest86 running too. Though I don't think that this is hardware-related error, because it seems to only affect explorer.exe and not other software or games.
Thanks

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: 2х8GiB, DDR4-2400, 15-15-15-35 CR2, no overclocking

Comment: Sounds OK. We'll see if the tests come up with something.

Comment: Thanks, will update you when I get any results.

Comment: Dism found some problems and fixed them, log link: pastebin.com/FMQiiTED
Will start memtest and leave pc alone until evening

Comment: No memtest errors

Comment: As Windows is unable to fix itself, I would suggest returning all components to a known state by doing [In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). Although this operation almost always succeeds harmlessly, ensure that you have good backups of your personal data before starting.

Comment: Eh, while resetting windows will most likely fix this crash, if it's software related, it isn't the move I'm willing to do now, considering potential data lost and time investment to set system up from scratch if anything goes south.
Thanks for the help though, I guess I'll wait for a few updates until I consider resetting my system.

Comment: This isn't resetting - it's exactly the same as any Windows major update and it will keep your data, apps and almost all Windows settings.